# One-hot encoding in pyspark with Multiple 1's in a row

Tags: python, pyspark, one-hot-encoding

I have a Python dataframe `final_df` as follows:

[image]

The rows have duplicate `ID` values. How can I have a one-hot encoded output as follows using pyspark?

[image]

I have converted it into a spark dataframe:

```
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(final_df)
```

And then collected unique values in `CONCEPTS` column as follows:

```
types = spark_df.select("CONCEPTS").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

But when I call the following:

```
types_expr = [F.when((F.col("CONCEPTS") == ty), 1).otherwise(0).alias(ty) for ty in types]
df = spark_df.select("ID", *types_expr)
df.show()
```

I am getting the following:

[image]

The solutions to other questions similar to this do not produce multiple 1's for a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [pivot](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) function of the GroupedData class as your are working only with 1's and 0's. Example code:

```
l =[( 115        ,'A' ),
( 116        , 'B' ),
( 118        , 'C' ),
( 121        , 'D' ),
( 125        , 'E' ),
( 127        , 'F' ),
( 127        , 'G' ),
( 127        , 'H' ),
( 136        , 'I' ),
( 136        , 'J' )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['id','concepts'])
df.groupBy('id').pivot('concepts').count().show()
```

Will lead to the following dataframe:

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+   
| id|   A|   B|   C|   D|   E|   F|   G|   H|   I|   J| 
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+ 
|136|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|   1|   1| 
|116|null|   1|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 
|115|   1|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 
|127|null|null|null|null|null|   1|   1|   1|null|null| 
|118|null|null|   1|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 
|125|null|null|null|null|   1|null|null|null|null|null| 
|121|null|null|null|   1|null|null|null|null|null|null| 
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

If needed replace the null values with the [fill](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill)-function.

---

Someone in the comments asked how this can be done with pandas. It is basically the same approach but the required function is [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l =[( 115        ,'A' ),
( 116        , 'B' ),
( 118        , 'C' ),
( 121        , 'D' ),
( 125        , 'E' ),
( 127        , 'F' ),
( 127        , 'G' ),
( 127        , 'H' ),
( 136        , 'I' ),
( 136        , 'J' )]

df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['id','concepts'] )
df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='concepts', aggfunc=len)
```

Output:

```py
concepts    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
id                                                        
115       1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
116       NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
118       NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
121       NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
125       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
127       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
136       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
```